How to overwrite the HEX color background for this? I'm embedding this into my website
<iframe title="For Him" src="https://shopmy.us/collections/public/1014078?noHeader=true" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1200px; border: none;" <body style="background-color: #FAF8EF"></iframe>

Color: #FAF8EF
I want the white background to be the above color.
I've tried inserting this <body style="background-color: #FAF8EF"> but I may not be placing it in the correct spot.
I've also tried this to no avail:
<body style="background-color: #FAF8EF;">

<iframe title="For Him" src="https://shopmy.us/collections/public/1014078?noHeader=true" style="width: 100%; min-height: 1200px; border: none;"></iframe></body>

Do you have any ideas?

You can't change the background color of an iframe, the page you want to embed has already a background color, you won't be able to override it.
